# Is it possible to override existing styled component styling from outside?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I would like to change the styling of an existing package (without css) what was built purely with styled components (100% css in js).

So let's say I've got a package: **superawesome-styled-components**, AND a code-base what already using these components.

example:

```
A.js
import { Button } from 'superawesome-styled-components'

function A() {
   return(
      <Button />
   )
}




B.js
import { Button } from 'superawesome-styled-components'

function A() {
   return(
      <Button />
   )
}




C.js
import { Button } from 'superawesome-styled-components'

function A() {
   return(
      <Button />
   )
}
```

As you can see I imported the Button in multiple files. AND here is the problem... How could I change the styling of the `<Button />` so it's would change in all instances. (without the need of opening each files, and change the button component)

***without using css***

**note I won't have access to the superawesome-styled-components**

Comment: why can't you modify the original `<Button />` component? That way it would reflect everywhere...

Comment: Unfortunately I won't have access to it.

Comment: You can use theming as an option. Depends if your `<Button />` component supports it. My guess is that it might. See here: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes you can... `styled-components` internally assign a className... You can use the chrome dev tools to see what that className is and override it via CSS...

[image]

See a working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/0yzzwk20yn

The primary button is supposed to be purple... but in the styles.css I'm overriding it and making it red...

Comment: Well this would be a go, but the team goes down absolutely on the 0 css way. (so unfortunately, this is a no go)

Comment: So you want to change the style of a button but can’t use css or touch the styled components... 

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the Button class after you import it, but before you use it (once, at the top of your final output file), so the framework that interprets it (react?) sees the change.

Depending on your build process, you may just need to add a js file to the page after your Button file loads, but before you use it. That file would override the js properties for styling. If you use a module loader this might get tricky but it should be doable.

I don't know react well, but it's ultimately just js so figure out where you need to inject the change and you should only have to do it once.

Start by looking at your file output order, that should give you an idea which file(s) need updating at which point to make it work.